# DAX to ignore column values (image URL) in a Matrix visual

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax

I have a matrix table visual with Calendar[Day] as the rows and Transactions[Country_Flag] as the column values. The Transactions[Country_Flag] is an image URL column displaying the country flag in the visual.

I'm planning to place an SVG into the matrix, and for that, I would need to calculate the total value of Transactions[Sales], ignoring the Transactions[Country_Flag] column while maintaining the filter on the rows for Calendar[Day].

I thought this DAX would make it easy:

```
Total_Sales_per_Day = 
    CALCULATE(
        [Total_Sales],
        ALL(Transactions[Country_Flag])
    )
```

However, it does not ignore Transactions[Country_Flag].

When I switch columns in the visual—instead of putting Transactions[Country_Flag], I use Transactions[Country_Name]—and apply the edited formula, it works just fine.

```
Total_Sales_per_Day = 
    CALCULATE(
        [Total_Sales],
        ALL(Transactions[Country_Name])
    )
```

Why is that? Can you please advise? I just can't figure it out. I thought it might have something to do with the fact that it is an image URL, but I'm not sure if that is the problem.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you share a .pbix with the issue?

Comment: I will have to create one because I was running it with real data...thanks!
will come back

Comment: I finished creating the sample file and the DAX was perfectly working there without any issues...same model, same columns types as in my organizational .pbix...so I really couldnt understand why is that...and I made one another attempt : previously the Transactions[Country_Flag] column was a calculated column...I tried recreating this column in Power Query instead and guess what? It is working now :)
I dont know why but it is working

Comment: Glad it is sorted.

Comment: Thanks for always giving a helping hand!

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the column Transactions[Country_Flag] in PowerQuery and it solved the issue...previously it was a calculated column